# Update dt columns based on named list

Tags: r, list, data.table, apply

Let's say, I have the following `my_dt` datatable:

| neutrons | spectrum | geography |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2.30 | -1.2 | KIEL |
| 2.54 | -1.6 | KIEL |
| 2.56 | -0.9 | JUNG |
| 2.31 | -0.3 | ANT |

Also I have the following named list (`my_list`):

```
> my_list
$particles   
[1] "neutrons"

$station   
[1] NA

$energy      
[1] "spectrum"

$area   
[1] "geography"

$gamma   
[1] NA
```

The values of this list correspond to the columns names from my dataset (if they exist, if they are absent - `NA`).
Based on my dataset and this list, I need to check which columns exist in `my_dt` and rename them (based on `my_list` names), and for `NA` values - I need to create columns filled with `NA`s.

So, I want to obtain the following dataset:

```
>final_dt
```

| particles | station | energy | area | gamma |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2.30 | NA | -1.2 | KIEL | NA |
| 2.54 | NA | -1.6 | KIEL | NA |
| 2.56 | NA | -0.9 | JUNG | NA |
| 2.31 | NA | -0.3 | ANT | NA |

I try to implement this using apply family functions, but at the moment I can't obtain exactly what I want.
So, I would be grateful for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**data.table** using `lapply`

```
library(data.table)

setDT(my_dt)
setDT(my_list)

final_dt <- setnames( my_list[, lapply( .SD, function(x){
  if( x %in% colnames(my_dt)){ my_dt[,x,with=F] }else{ NA } } ) ],
  names(my_list) )

final_dt
   particles station energy area gamma
1:      2.30      NA   -1.2 KIEL    NA
2:      2.54      NA   -1.6 KIEL    NA
3:      2.56      NA   -0.9 JUNG    NA
4:      2.31      NA   -0.3  ANT    NA
```

**base R** using `sapply`

```
setDF(my_dt)
setDF(my_list)

data.frame( sapply( my_list, function(x) if(!is.na(x)){ my_dt[,x] }else{ NA } ) )
  particles station energy area gamma
1      2.30      NA   -1.2 KIEL    NA
2      2.54      NA   -1.6 KIEL    NA
3      2.56      NA   -0.9 JUNG    NA
4      2.31      NA   -0.3  ANT    NA
```

##### Data

```
my_dt <- structure(list(neutrons = c(2.3, 2.54, 2.56, 2.31), spectrum = c(-1.2, 
-1.6, -0.9, -0.3), geography = c("KIEL", "KIEL", "JUNG", "ANT"
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L))

my_list <- list(particles = "neutrons", station = NA, energy = "spectrum", 
    area = "geography", gamma = NA)
```

Comment: Thank you, Andre! Applied this solution to my data and recieved the error: `Error in `[.data.table`(xxx, , x) : j (the 2nd argument inside [...]) is a single symbol but column name 'x' is not found.`

Comment: @Hilary This is a `base R` solution. Use `setDF(my_dt)` and `setDF(my_list)`. If you want a pure `data.table` solution you should probably change the tag `datatable` to `data.table`. Small but improtant difference :)

Comment: Thanks a lot, I changed the tag! Do you have any ideas of how your solution can be transformed into a pure `data.table` solution?

Comment: @Hilary See edits. Hope this works for you!

Answer (score 1):

This may not meet your needs, but since I had come up with this separately thought I would share just in case. You can use `setnames` to rename the columns based on `my_list`. After that, add in the missing column names with values of `NA`. Finally, you can use `setcolorder` to reorder based on your list if desired.

```
library(data.table)

my_vec <- unlist(my_list)
setnames(my_dt, names(my_vec[match(names(my_dt), my_vec)]))
my_dt[, (setdiff(names(my_vec), names(my_dt))) := NA]
setcolorder(my_dt, names(my_vec))
my_dt
```

**Output**

```
   particles station energy area gamma
1:      2.30      NA   -1.2 KIEL    NA
2:      2.54      NA   -1.6 KIEL    NA
3:      2.56      NA   -0.9 JUNG    NA
4:      2.31      NA   -0.3  ANT    NA
```

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a simple code that should do the job for you:

```
l = list(c = 'cc', a = 'aa', b = NA) # replace this with your my_list

dt = data.frame(aa = 1:3, cc = 2:4) # replace this with my_dt 

dtl = data.frame(l)

names(dt) = names(l)[na.omit(match(l, names(dt)))]

m = merge(dt, dtl[!is.element(names(dtl), names(dt))])
```

Comment: Thank you, Matija! But I need pure `data.table` solution..

Comment: @Hilary, you really should specify that constraint in the question, it is not safe to assume it the way I read it.

Comment: I'm sure that there is a way to convert data.table into data.frame (and back if required), for example use as.data.frame(my_dt)

Comment: `l = my_list # replace this with your my_list`

`dt = as.data.frame(my_dt) # replace this with my_dt `

`dtl = data.frame(l)`

`names(dt) = names(l)[na.omit(match(l, names(dt)))]`

`m = merge(dt, dtl[!is.element(names(dtl), names(dt))])`